# Include correct gap to mimic a PDB file

Tags: python, awk

I have .txt file which looks like

```
ATOM 14 H ASP 121 -3.734 -19.261 8.867 1.00 1.00
ATOM 15 N ASN 122 -1.927 -19.244 6.166 1.00 1.00
ATOM 16 CA ASN 122 -0.564 -19.362 5.619 1.00 1.00
ATOM 17 C ASN 122 -0.411 -18.664 4.236 1.00 1.00
ATOM 18 O ASN 122 0.724 -18.237 3.907 1.00 1.00
ATOM 19 CB ASN 122 -0.073 -20.801 5.520 1.00 1.00
ATOM 20 CG ASN 122 -0.027 -21.567 6.844 1.00 1.00
ATOM 21 OD1 ASN 122 -0.160 -20.977 7.885 1.00 1.00
ATOM 22 ND2 ASN 122 0.209 -22.814 6.737 1.00 1.00
ATOM 23 H ASN 122 -2.363 -20.148 6.283 1.00 1.00
ATOM 24 HA ASN 122 0.051 -18.761 6.289 1.00 1.00
```

I want it look like the following (PDB format but not necessarily .pdb extension)

```
ATOM      1   N  ASP 121        -3.672 -18.295   8.578  1.00  1.00
ATOM      2  CA  ASP 121        -3.891 -18.124   7.134  1.00  1.00
ATOM      3   C  ASP 121        -2.564 -18.105   6.358  1.00  1.00
ATOM      4   O  ASP 121        -2.035 -17.071   6.084  1.00  1.00
ATOM      5  CB  ASP 121        -4.660 -16.822   6.833  1.00  1.00
ATOM      6  CG  ASP 121        -4.169 -15.556   7.552  1.00  1.00
ATOM      7 OD1  ASP 121        -4.570 -14.506   7.201  1.00  1.00
ATOM      8 OD2  ASP 121        -3.377 -15.594   8.529  1.00  1.00
ATOM      9   H  ASP 121        -2.748 -17.957   8.804  1.00  1.00
ATOM     10  HA  ASP 121        -4.559 -18.884   6.728  1.00  1.00
ATOM     11 HB2  ASP 121        -4.510 -16.695   5.761  1.00  1.00
ATOM     12 HB3  ASP 121        -5.701 -16.929   7.138  1.00  1.00
ATOM     13   H  ASP 121        -4.406 -17.764   9.026  1.00  1.00
```

Any help with explanation of the code will be really appreciated!!

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Why is this tagged both python and awk?

Comment: @oguzismail, I think because they are suggesting viable ways to solve it that they are familiar with, but without showing what they have tried. Not saying they are doing it for an assignment, but I have solved exactly that in Python and C when in school.

Comment: Try `column -t file`

Comment: @anubhava way better than my ugly command :) thanks

Comment: I didn't mention .pdb extension. I thought it is clear that PDB format means the gaps according to RCSB PDB formatting style

Comment: I know the PDB format. I also checked that column -t is not exactly the PDB gap but it is close enough. I used my solution. I previously tagged with awk and bash if I remember correctly. I am using an external programme to get only x y z values and then combining awk and python output to get the gaps as mentioned in my question. Hence I tagged both. It is a long story.

Comment: Sorry @Jakub I have no intention to offend you. I simply don't understand your question. You mean do I want a output with my desired formatting with .txt extension? Answer is Yes. What you mean by 'printing to screen'?

Comment: @Soumendranath Bhakat Could you answer my question. Does the output of `column -t file` go to a file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align your text to the right, you can use numpy. Enter number of characters for each column using fmt.

```
import numpy as np

# Format each column
fmt = ('%s', '%7s', '%4s', '%5s', '%4s', '%14s', '%8s', '%8s', '%6s', '%6s')

# Open file
txt = np.genfromtxt('/pdb.txt', delimiter=' ', dtype=np.str, encoding=None)

# Save file
np.savetxt('/pdb_new.txt', txt, fmt=fmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force method, in the language of your choice, loop over each item of each column and determine the widest number of characters per column. Then use something like `printf` or `str.format` and their microlanguage for string formatting to output each column padded by the maximum width, plus whatever buffer is desired between each column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple cat/awk command that works

```
cat test1.txt | awk '{printf("ATOM  %5d %4s %3s %5d    %8s%8s%8s  1.00  1.00\n", $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8)}'
```